# Minimal number of linearly dependent rank-1 projectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, matrix-theory

What is the minimal number of linearly dependent rank-1 projectors $\vec v \vec v^t$ in dimension n, under the condition that every set of n column vectors $\vec v$ is linearly independent.

PS: the question can be restated in a more general form. Given $m$ linearly dependent rank-$1$ projectors $\vec v \vec v^t$ such that every set of $m-1$ projectors is linearly independent, what is that maximal possible dimension of the space spanned by the vectors $\vec v$?

Comment: In the meantime, I realised that the answer is 2n.

Comment: I have an idea how to get $\le2n$, but I don't know how to get $\not<2n$. Can you post the details?

Comment: Is your idea the following? Take two orthogonal bases. The sum of the corresponding n projectors are equal to the identity for each basis. Thus, there are 2n linearly dependent projectors (for generic pairs of bases).

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I found this proof that the minimum is $2n$. First, let me prove that the minimum is smaller or equal to $2n$. Let $\{\vec v_1,\dots,\vec v_n\}$ and $\{\vec v_{1+n},\dots,\vec v_{2n}\}$ be two sets of orthogonal vectors. It is always possible to choose the two bases such that every set of $n$ vectors among the $2n$ vectors is independent. The sum of the $n$ projectors associated to one basis is equal to the identity matrix. Thus the $2n$ projectors are linearly dependent. Let me prove that the minimum cannot be strictly smaller than $2n$. Suppose that the minimum $m$ is $<2n$. Evidently, $m$ is greater than $n-1$. By hypothesis, there are coefficients $a_i$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^m a_i P_i=0$, where $P_i=\vec v_i\vec v_i^t$. The sum of the first $n$ projectors is a rank-n matrix, whereas the sum of the remaining projectors has rank less than $n$, which is impossible. $\square$

Comment: What are your $P_i$'s, and how are they related to the $a_i$'s? And what then about the ranks?

Comment: I change the answer accordingly.

Comment: No, no coefficient can be zero, otherwise $m$ is not the minimum.